# How do Delete view and action get the model id?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In a standard MVC app, scaffolding controller with views gives a `Delete` view with this Razor form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
```

Nowhere in the `Delete` view is any `id` field, hidden or not.

Then the controller for that view has this action:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(long id)
{
    ....
}
```

Where does this action get its `id` parameter value from? Is it somehow extracted from the only form value posted, the anti-forgery token `__RequestVerificationToken`, during some sort of model binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a GET method with a signature

```
public ActionResult Delete(long id)
```

and you using the default route (or at least a route definition containing `/{id}`)

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

When you navigate to that method, say using `/yourController/Delete/10`, the value of `id` is `10`, and that is added to the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag generated by your `Html.BeginForm()` method. When you submit the form, the value of the `id` parameter is bound for the route value in the forms `action` attribute (the `DefaultModelBinder` reads values from the form collection (any inputs you might have) as well as route values and query strings (among others)

Comment: Aah, yes, I once knew the binder used all values, but somewhere lost track and took on the assumption it only used form data for post requests.

Answer (score 1):

The id is passed as parameter when you redirected to the `Delete` action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(long id)
{
    return View();
}
```

and since it is part of the original url (look at your browser address bar at the moment the Delete view is displayed) it will be preserved by the `Html.BeginForm()` helper - now look at the generated HTML markup and you will see this:

```
<form action="/somecontroller/delete/123" method="post">
    ...    
</form>
```

That's where the `id` is coming from - the action of the generated form.

Comment: Thank you for the much needed refresher, Darin.